# Blender Python: Output Paragraph of Text?

Tags: python, add-on, development

Is there any built-in support for automatic line breaks when writing text to the UI, such as through the `layout.label()` function?

For example, if I set text that is wider than a panel, it would automatically insert a line break to create two lines instead of the one?

Comment: This currently work in progress see [D7496](https://developer.blender.org/D7496)